# RabbitMQ receiver need to check for new message in queue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rabbitmq

I am using spring and `Hibernate` with `RabbitMQ`.

I am facing problem that when sender send message to receiver(consumer) that time message add to queue successfully but receiver have to check every time to get new message from queue.

This is increasing overhead.

Is there any proper solution using that receiver automatic knows that new message in a queue.

Comment: How did you implement the receiver? The [simplest tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) says that you should start another thread that will wait for messages.  "`QueueingConsumer.nextDelivery()` _blocks until another message has been delivered from the server._"

Comment: I am create a web application so every time my web browser need to send request to server for new message. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: I don't want to wait receiver until sender send message. means is there any callback that ping to my receiver for new message?

Comment: You can't have a direct callback from RabbitMQ broker to your code. What you need is to spin off a consumer in a different thread. That thread then will block waiting for new messages. Check `basic_consume`  and `basic.deliver`.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem in the question. As I understand from the comment above your problem is that the browser needs to poll the server for the message. That means the problem is not in RabbitMQ but http layer. What you need is [Cometd](http://cometd.org/) or [Atmosphere](http://cometd.org/)